# AMSART: Including author's webpage among contact information

Tags: amsart

In `amsart`, how do you add (a hyperlink to) a personal webpage among the author's contact information?

Clearly, the proposed solution should be able to support multiple authors, just like `\email`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\author[Surname2]{Name2 Surname2}
\address{University2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What about `\urladdr{...}`? Does that work?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Done. Thanks for the heads-up. `\urladdr{...}` seem to display the url at the top of the page despite the `\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}`; how do I fix this? Besides, I'd like the label to be *Web-page*, and not *URL*.

Comment: Without `amsaddr` it would be `\renewcommand*{\urladdrname}{\itshape Web-page}` to change the label. With that package, you have to do `\usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchcmd{\@setaddresses}{URL}{Web-page}{}{}`. Can't help you with the wrong placement. Please contact the maintainer to tell him about this (wrong) behaviour. The email-address is in the third line of his manual.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks. In the end, I decided to remove that package because with two co-authors the footnote would become too long; and now your solution works fine. However, emailing the maintainer seems a good idea.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- can you answer this, please?  (i don't know anything about the `amsaddr` package; it's not from ams.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton done. But it is nor really complete. Well. The topic seems to be closed for Ryo so we can close here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the command `\urladdr{...}` a try. But this does not seem to work with the `foot` option of `amsaddr`.

Regarding the change of label:

Without amsaddr it would be `\renewcommand*{\urladdrname}{\itshape Web-page}` to change the label. With that package, you have to do `\usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchcmd{\@setaddresses}{URL}{Web-page}{}{}`. Can't help you with the wrong placement. Please contact the maintainer to tell him about this (wrong) behaviour. The email-address is in the third line of his manual.