# AMSART: Including two dates

Tags: datetime, amsart

In `amsart`, how do you include two dates (in the footnotes)?

Specifically, another one (displayed after the label *Last update*) in addition to the default one (`\date`), with the same options.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a minimal document which we can compile. We do not want to set up a whole example for you just in order to add a fixed date.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : Upon a change of mind, I revised the question. I hope it is not a problem.

Comment: Would this trick be enough for you? `\date{September 14, 2015; \textit{Last updated}:~\today}`. This needs no further patching of your class and the package `amsaddr`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Actually, yes, thank you: it would serve my purpose well. However, I'd like to learn how to set up a second date too (it's always useful to learn something new after all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some infrastructure to `amsart.cls`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\makeatletter
\def\@setdate{%
  \datename\ \@date
  \ifx\last@update\@empty\else
    .\ \lastupdatename\ \last@update
  \fi
  \@addpunct.%
}
\def\lastupdatename{\textit{Last Update}:}
\def\lastupdate#1{\gdef\last@update{#1}}
\let\last@update\@empty
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}
\author[Surname]{Name Surname}
\address{University}
\email{email@email.com}
\date{14/09/2015}
\lastupdate{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add `\vspace{1mm}` between the email address and the two dates? (I tried, but it doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: @Ryo Yes, but you need to modify the redefinition of `\@maketitle` made by `amsaddr.sty`. I see no improvement, though. Of course, the journal which you submit the paper to will reject these changes anyway.

Comment: I see. And how do you do that?

Comment: @Ryo Ask a new question; but this is quite complicated, because other bits of information *could* follow the email address and the date could not be set. And, as I said, I see no real improvement in the output.

Comment: By the way, could you have a look at [this other (somewhat related) issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267443/amsart-including-authors-webpage-among-contact-information)?